# Websocket не работает

Tags: websocket

Никак не могу понять, что нужно, что бы написать простейший чат на php с помощью websocket.
Например я тестирую на javascript:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");

socket.onopen = function() {
  alert("Соединение установлено.");
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert("Получены данные " + event.data);
  // по идее должно срабатывать в обеих браузерах если получен ответ.
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
};

$("button").click(function(){ // это jquery
    socket.send("Привет");
})
```

Если посмотреть на demo этих чатов https://github.com/morozovsk/websocket-examples, то всё работает в разных браузерах. Почему не работает на денвере?

Comment: Потому, что сервер должен также работать с веб сокетами. Например вот библиотека на php [Ratchet
WebSockets for PHP](http://socketo.me/)  или вручника писать. У вас что на сервере написано?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский У меня на сервере нет websocketa. Это просто библиотека или что?

Comment: Я так понимаю, мне нужно арендовать сервер, что бы установить этот websocket ?

Comment: Сокет - это интерфейс взаимодействия клиента и сервера)) Если клиент общается через сокеты, то на стороне сервера надо реализовать аналогичный способ общения. (не зря в вашей ссылке есть примеры с папками клиент и сервер). А главный класс реализации находится [Здесь](https://github.com/morozovsk/websocket/blob/master/Server.php) У `php` класс работы с сокетами находится в `php_sockets.dll`. О работе можно почитать [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sockets.php) или [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/). Если не хочется вручную писать реализацию используются вспом. библиотеки.

Comment: У других серверных языков по работе с сокетами используются свои классы. В общем, серверный язык уже имеет в себе библиотеки по работе с сокетами. Нужно только реализовать логику на стороне сервера

Comment: Все комментарии хорошо, но у меня ничего не выходит. Я уже и сервер арендовал, установил dll для работы с сокетами и ничего не работает. Помогите плиз по скайпу: kylaksizov

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32458/discussion-between--and--).